# Count wrong capitalization as wrong answer in js quiz

Tags: javascript, wordpress

In this [js quiz script](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/wp-content/themes/cassie/js/quiz-calendar.js) everything is converted everything to lower case so that, for example, both *mercredi* and *Mercredi* are counted as correct answers. I believe this is due to the following line:

`else if( user_answers[i].toLowerCase().trim()==real_answers[i])`

For [this quiz](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/quizzes-and-tests/calendar-quiz), the case matters: in question #1, I want only *mercredi* to be counted as correct, but not *Mercredi*. So I changed the above line to

`else if( user_answers[i].trim()==real_answers[i])`

However, it's still counting both lower and upper case as correct, so what else do I need to change? Here's the relevant section of code:

```
points=0;
message='<div id="results">';
inc=1;
for(i=0;i<real_answers.length;i++) 

{
if (typeof user_answers[i]=='undefined' || user_answers[i]=='') 
{

//message+='<p>'+parseInt(i+1) + ')' +' You didn't answer this question.</p>';
$('#special_'+i).text(i+inc+') '+'You didn\'t answer this question.');
  $('#special_'+i).show();
  $(":input[name ='question_"+i+"']").prop('disabled',true);
}

else if( user_answers[i].trim()==real_answers[i]) 
{

points++;
//message+='<p>' +parseInt(i+1)  + ')' +' Très bien !</p>';
$('#special_'+i).text(i+inc+') '+'Très bien !');
  $('#special_'+i).addClass('correct');
  $('#special_'+i).show();

}

else 
{

$('#special_'+i).text($('#special_'+i).text().replace(i+inc+') '+' ',''));
$('#special_'+i).prepend(i+inc+') '+' ');
$('#special_'+i).show();
}
```

Comment: Actually i did try the quizz and it worked well. Maybe your cache didn't refresh well can you confirm that?

Comment: I cleared my entire site cache and tried three different browsers, including an anonymous one. So you're saying that you put Mercredi with a capital M for the first question, and it was counted wrong?

Comment: yes i wrote "Mercredi" and it was counted wrong i tried with chrome & firefox and IE

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a caching problem even though I cleared everything and tried different browsers. It's still not working properly for me, but it is for others.